# Image with text not working and add some Html

Tags: php, html, css

I want to upload an image with some text on it, but when I'm uploading my PHP script it's not working with an image, it shows error every time.  And also i want to add some html in the same file I had tried to put that php In html tag and show that image in the center how to do so

My PHP code is:

result.php

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg');
    $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);
    $font_path = 'font.TTF';
    $text = $_GET["name"];
    imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);
    imagejpeg($jpg_image);
    imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

`$_GET["name"];` is used for getting text form HTML by input tag, and for your information I have used form method to get the text I want an working example.

The image I want to use is http://images.visitcanberra.com.au/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg

So please use that image only while giving answer

Comment: Please paste the error message

Comment: The main error is that it is not displaying the image with text only showing a blank tab

Comment: check the result of the functions you use  - for example if `imagettftext` returns FALSE, it means the function completes unsuccessfully, so you should check if the font.TTF is availabe, do you have GD library installed, FreeType library installed and so on. Yo don't have to ask  questions, whitout evenchecking the result of the operations you made!

Comment: If I'want to use any default font what should I use for that and how to install GD library on server and when I'm using                                         `<?php
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(300, 100);
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
    $string = $_GET["myname"];
    imagestring($im, 20, 5, 5,  $string, $text_color);
    imagejpeg($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
    ?> `   it is perfectly working

Comment: I have checked I have installed GD library on my web server by using this php `<?php
if (extension_loaded('gd') && function_exists('gd_info')) {
    echo "PHP GD library is installed on your web server";
}
else {
    echo "PHP GD library is NOT installed on your web server";
}
?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line will describe the name of image `$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg');` and image name is `image.jpg`

as you mentioned *The image I want to use is http://images.visitcanberra.com.au/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg*

this is image name `canberra_hero_image.jpg` right, how come php will work, first rename and use single name
better rename you `php`

**this is the reason you see only text and not image**

Comment: can we use it like this because this image is not in my server                                                              `$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('http://images.visitcanberra.com.au/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg');`

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from '$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg');' to this code

```
$image_path = ''http://images.visitcanberra.com.au/images/canberra_hero_ima‌​ge.jpg'';

$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path);
```